# Unity Tilemaps not Rendering as I move camera

Tags: unity, c#, camera

As I move the main camera in my Unity game towards the left or right, the camera just stops rendering any of the tilemaps in the scene.

[image]

Here, the camera is at x = 25.7, and the preview isn't showing anything (Neither is the game view), but as I move the camera inwards towards x = 24.7, everything renders normally...

I can clearly see the tilemap objects in the scene view though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem! The camera doesn't render the objects even though they exist because the camera moves far enough away from them, to not render.

The Tilemaps I create are centered at 0,0 (even the ones that generate the tiles far away). So when the camera moves a certain distance away from them, it just stops rendering the tilemaps.

To fix it, I just had to centre the tilemaps closer to the place they would be generating their tiles (chunkNo * chunkSize).

This fixed the issue!

Comment: **Thank you** for answering your own question. Somehow Unity was setting impossibly low chunk sizes by default, even though my tilemaps are never far from zero; this answer helped immensely!

Comment: you can share your code ? please